# Cool bubble effect using something like CCParticle in Cocos2d (no third party tools)

Tags: ios, graphics, cocos2d-iphone, effects, particles

I would like to achieve a cool particle effect like in [here](http://www.lifeofandroid.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/Bubble_Shoot_main_580.png).

The bubble should be similar to an explosion starting from the centre and expanding. I'd like to add an animated wave coming out from the left and right side of the bubble and looking like [this](http://telepics.net/uploads/pictures/big_images/Animated_Music_Wave.jpg). I guess I could use to two distinct animation and put together as I assume this has never been done in a Cocos2d game.

Also, I would like to avoid using non-Cocos2d tools as [particle designer](http://particledesigner.71squared.com/). In chapter 1 of the [Cocos2d cookbook](http://cocos2dcookbook.com/) I found some cool particle examples and the code doesn't seem too complex. Instead, using third party tools I need to import their classes and use their file format to create particles and I have to pay. Even more there doesn't seem to be many particle effect files shared (at least not the ones I want).

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I added a comment with a theory on how the first of the two animation could work.

Comment: Actually, if I look closer to that bubble explosion effect I can distinguish two elements. One is a particle effect like "ParticleGalaxy" and "ParticleFlower" and the other one could be a PNG image (the white bubble) that gets rescaled. So this could form the first part of the effect. For the second part (waves) I guess the question is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Your best chance is with Particle Designer. You can modify the emitters in the library and visualize your changes. It's the easiest way to achieve a great effect. Once you find the combination of values that you like , you can simply create an emitter from code and set all those properties yourself. You don't have to pay or use any class (which you actually don't have to , it's already built in cocos2D) . So just download the free version of Particle Designer and then set the values from code. It's the same thing , it only takes a bit more work to do.

Comment: In my question I had specifically said that I did not wanted to use Particle Designer. Also, by simply changing the patterns of the particles I will not be able to achieve the effect that I want. I need two seperate animations and merge them together which doesn't seem to be possible with a single project in Particle Designer. I am working on this and I might post a video with solution if I get the hang of it or if someone else comes up with another solution.

Comment: I know you said that. But visually handling it it's the easiest way. You can make each of those animations and create 2 emitters on the same position. I suggested that because you said the reasons you don't want to use Particle Designer are : you have to pay and you have to import their classes. And I told you that you don't have to do any of those. Btw , there is nothing you can do in code more than you can do in Particle Designer. It's basically the same thing since   it has all the properties you can set in code.